# Write the firm's expected cost as a function of d.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

[image]

[image]

I know the expected cost here is 15, given that it's a uniform distribution from 10 to 20 days but I'm not quite sure what this general form equation would look like.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $0\leq A\leq d\leq B$
$$\begin{aligned}E[|X-d|]&=\frac{1}{B-A+1}\sum_{k=A}^B|k-d|=\\&=\frac{1}{B-A+1}\bigg(\sum_{k=A}^{d}(d-k)+\sum_{k=d+1}^B(k-d)\bigg)=\\
&=\frac{1}{B-A+1}\bigg(d(d-A+1)-\frac{d(d+1)-A(A-1)}{2}+\\
&+\frac{B(B+1)-d(d+1)}{2}-d(B-d)\bigg)=\\
&=\frac{2d(d-A-B)+A(A-1)+B(B+1)}{2(B-A+1)}\end{aligned}$$
Then you have to plug in the values for $A,B$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the intuition for line two and three? I'm a little confused.

Comment: @aero26 line 2 uses the property of absolute value hinted at in Hint 2. The third line uses the [rules of series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Sums_of_powers).